# Orthographic camera produces strange results

Tags: opengl, mathematics

I've created a basic orthographic camera using the following view projection matrix:

```
2 / (right - left), 0, 0, -((right + left) / (right - left)),
0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, -((top + bottom) / (top - bottom)),
0, 0, -2 / (zFar - zNear), -((zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear)),
0, 0, 0, 1
```

where right = 1280, left = 0, top = 0, bottom = 720, zFar = 1.0 and zNear = -1.0

The matrix gets used in the glsl shader like below:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_TexCoord;

uniform mat4 u_ViewProjection;
uniform mat4 u_Transform;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;

void main()
{
    v_TexCoord =  a_TexCoord;
    gl_Position = u_ViewProjection * u_Transform * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
}
```

where the u_Transform uniform is passed a simple identity matrix.

And I have declared a default rectangle that I am trying to get to the middle of my screen:

```
    float vertices[] = {
        // positions         // texcoords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f    // top left 
    };
```

This results in the folowing image showing a single diagonal line:
[image: image with single diagonal line]

The strange thing is that if I upscale the rectangle coordinates to the following:

```
        float vertices[] = {
        // positions         // texcoords
         1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f    // top left
```

It shows a full rectangle like below:
[image: image with rectangle in top right corner]

**Expected result:** In both cases it should show a rectangle, with the second rectangle being larger.
**Actual result:** The first case doesnt even produce a rectangle, while the upscaled coordinates do show a rectangle.

**My question:** Is the problem in the math, and if so, what causes this behavior or should this be the expected result and am I wrong in my understanding of the model view projection matrix.